# Spring-Boot 2+ forces CGLIB proxy even with proxyTargetClass = false

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

The proxification setup seems to have changed between Spring-Boot 1.5+ and 2.+.

In Spring 1.5.20 with @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = false) or just @EnableAspectJAutoProxy or even no annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy I would get a JdkDynamicAopProxy.
And with @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true) I would get CGLIB enhanced classes. OK all good.

With the same code with Spring 2.1.4,  I get a CGLIB enhanced ServiceImpl all the time whatever the config.

I did not managed to have JdkDynamicAopProxy proxies with Spring 2+.

Is there still a way to do it ?

Here is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = false)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        MyService service = context.getBean(MyService.class);
        service.execute();
    }
}


@Aspect
@Component
public class ChronoAspect {
    @Around("execution(* com.example.demo.service..*.*(..))")
    public Object chronoAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // .....
    }

}

public interface MyService {
    void execute();
}

@Component
public class ServiceImpl implements MyService {
    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("Hello execute from Service.execute");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that [Spring Boot issue #12194](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12194) explains your problem. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: yes I saw those issues.  They seem to say that problems arise when you mix different proxy intentions : transaction + aspectj  + ... 
But in my example, above there is only one way of doing it  and there is already a problem !  If they can't fix it, they should remove the properties to set it, because they don't work anymore...

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue.

Currently you can only set

```
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=false
```

in your config file to force it to use JDKProxy.