# Using @SafeVarags in a spring boot @Autowired class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cglib

I have a pretty simple use-case in spring boot (currently 2.7, we do have plans to upgrade down the line) around a DAO:

```java
@Repository
public class Dao {

   private final DbMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public Dao(DbMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

   @SafeVarargs
   public final Flux<Dto> getAll(Consumer<Dto>... filters) {
      return Flux.fromIterable(LibraryQueryBuilder. builder()
              .filters(filters)
              .build()
              .execute(mapper)
              .getAll());
   }
}
```

This is perfectly valid java, but during runtime I see that mapper is null. During my investigation, I ran into: [Spring: Accessing field from final method returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386068/spring-accessing-field-from-final-method-returning-null) which lead me to [Spring-Boot 2+ forces CGLIB proxy even with proxyTargetClass = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55853108/spring-boot-2-forces-cglib-proxy-even-with-proxytargetclass-false) and [GitHub Issue 12194](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12194) which were both disappointing responses in the context of this issue.

Considering `@SafeVarargs` is a Java core language feature to stop compiler warnings and requires the method to be final, and I don't want to see warnings all over my usage code when I'm using the varags safely is there any way to get `@SafeVarargs` to play nice with spring boot?

Comment: Is this **really** your dao or is there something else on there like `@Transactional` or some other aspect in your library that leads to proxy creation? Something triggers the need for a proxy which won't work with a `final` method.

Comment: I forgot to add the `@Repository`, good catch. Edited the question.

Comment: `@Repository` will lead to proxy creation, as that is needed to intercept the methods and do the exception translation.

Comment: I'm aware, but I'm hoping there was a way to disable CGLIB as the `@Configuration` seems to have a way to do so.

Is there a better pattern I should consider if there's no work around in that case?

Comment: No there isn't, you need a proxy as there are no interfaces on this class this will automatically be a cglib proxy. There is no way around that. `@Configuration` classes are processed differently as regular components.